# Regex: Find a string without a particular character in a particular spot

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a single-line string using the following regex:

```
=949.+\$h[^1]\$.+
```

However, the `\$h[^1]\$` string can contain 10 and 11 in addition to a 1.  I want to find the tens and elevens but NOT the ones.

So I want to find:
**$h10** and **$h11** but NOT **$h1**

Thoughts?

to clarify, I'd like it to find 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 but not 1

Comment: =949.+\$h1[01]\$.+ if you just want 10 and 11 you got the 1 for both

Comment: Which programming language ?

Comment: No particular language.  I'm using Notepad++ on a text file

Comment: While =949.+\$h1[01]\$.+ does find the 10 and 11, I still need it to find 2 through 9 as well.  Sorry should have made that more clear

Comment: So, to clarify, I'd like it to find 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 but not 1

Comment: @Marc No it's clear for me, check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\$h(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11)
```

***DEMO:***
http://regex101.com/r/lX4mS5

If you want to match everything except `$h1`, you can use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
\$h[\d]{1,2}(?<!(\$h1))
```

***DEMO:*** 
http://regex101.com/r/bS8mA2

Comment: This definitely works for my purposes, but for future reference what if I wanted to match anything but a "1"?  Just in case there is a 12 or a 13 or whatever else

Comment: Not beautiful at all xD but working ^^ I hope there is something else but I can't find it myself >-<

Comment: @CladClad I've updated my answer to match "anything but a 1".

Comment: @Marc I'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (without looking around):

```
\$h([2-9]|\d{2,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kZdt3vKwMQfvVwez)